# If $f_n,g_n \in L^1$ and $f_n,g_n \to 0$, show $\int_A (2f_n g_n)/(1+f_n^2+g_n^2)\to 0$, when $A$ has finite measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ be sequences of nonnegative function in $L^1(\mathbb R)$, for which
$$
f_n \to 0, \\
g_n \to 0,
$$
almost everywhere.
Show
$$
\int_A \frac{2f_n g_n}{1+f_n^2+g_n^2} \to 0,
$$
when $A \subset \mathbb R$ is a set of finite measure.

Define
$$
h_n = \frac{2f_n g_n}{1+f_n^2+g_n^2}.
$$
I know
$$
h_n \le 2f_n g_n,
$$
but I can't use a convergence theorem, because the product of integrable function may fail to be integrable.
I considered uniform integrability
$$
\text{Since } 
f_n \in L^1: \forall \epsilon, \exists \delta : m(B) < \delta \to \int_B f_n <\epsilon,
$$
where $m(\cdot)$ is Lebesgue measure.
To use that, I write $A=\cup_m B_{n,m}$ where the index $n$ is associated to $f_n$.
I can't go further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $0 \le h_n \le g_n$ since $\dfrac{2f_n}{1 + f_n^2} \le 1$.  Thus $h_n \to 0$.  You also have $0 \le h_n \le 1$ since $\dfrac{2f_n g_n}{1 + f_n^2 + g_n^2} \le 1$.  Since $A$ has finite measure, this provides a majorant of the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Egorov's theorem. Where there is uniform convergence, no problem, and on "the small set", the integrand is bounded by $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The only suggestion you might still need is: $2f_ng_n \le f_n^2 + g_n^2$. This is what gives the bound ($\frac{a}{1+a} \le 1$).